# I want to know(print) state of one thread from another thread... can we do that?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create two `Threads`.One to display something and after that it will go to **Wait state**.Then the second thread should start executing and it should print the state of the first thread(i.e waiting state) and after displaying it should notify and the first Thread should continue executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a small program for you. Please check if it meets your requirement. We can beautify the code later. Please elaborate your requirements more, if it is not meeting your expectations.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyThread1 th1 = new MyThread1();
    MyThread2 th2 = new MyThread2();
    //Allow thread 1 to run first
    Shareable shareable = new Shareable();
    shareable.threadToRun = th1.getName();
    th1.setAnotherThread(th2);
    th1.setShareable(shareable);
    th2.setAnotherThread(th1);
    th2.setShareable(shareable);
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
}
}
class Shareable {
    volatile String threadToRun;
}
class MyThread1 extends Thread {

private Shareable shareable;
private Thread anotherThread;

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (shareable) {
        waitForTurn();
        System.out.println(getName() +  " I am doing first task. After that wait for next Thread to finish.");
        shareable.threadToRun = anotherThread.getName();
        shareable.notifyAll();
        waitForTurn();
        System.out.println(getName() +  " I am doing next task now.");
    }
}

private void waitForTurn(){
    if(!shareable.threadToRun.equals(getName())){
        try {
            shareable.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void setShareable(Shareable shareable){
    this.shareable = shareable;
}
public void setAnotherThread(Thread anotherThread){
    this.anotherThread = anotherThread;
}


}
class MyThread2 extends Thread {

private Shareable shareable;
private Thread anotherThread;

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (shareable) {
        waitForTurn();
        System.out.println(getName() +  " I am doing task now. Another Thread " + anotherThread.getName() + " is in state " + anotherThread.getState());
        shareable.threadToRun = anotherThread.getName();
        shareable.notifyAll();
    }
}

private void waitForTurn(){
    if(!shareable.threadToRun.equals(getName())){
        try {
            shareable.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void setShareable(Shareable shareable){
    this.shareable = shareable;
}
public void setAnotherThread(Thread anotherThread){
    this.anotherThread = anotherThread;
}
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Thread-0 I am doing first task. After that wait for next Thread to finish.
Thread-1 I am doing task now. Another Thread Thread-0 is in state WAITING
Thread-0 I am doing next task now.
```